# Prime numbers in a given range using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I am trying to print prime numbers less than 'n'.The code is below:

```
def prime_numbers(n):
    A=[1 for i in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))):
        if A[i]==1:
            for j in range(i*2,n,i):
                A[j]=0
    for i in range(n):
        if A[i]:
            print(i)
```

Output for

```
prime_numbers(10)
```

is

```
0
1
2
3
5
7
9
```

The program correctly prints for 100. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Hint: the square root of 10 is 3.16. The range end point is *not included*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end point in a `range()` is not included. Since `sqrt(10)` is `3.1623`, your `range()` loops to 2 and no further, and the multiples of 3 are not removed from your list. Your code works for 100, because it doesn't matter if you test for multiples 10 (those are already covered by 2 and 5).

The same issue applies to your other loops; if you want to include `n` itself as a candidate prime number you should also include it in the other ranges.

Note that you also want to ignore 0 and 1, those are not primes. You could add `A[0] = A[1] = False` at the top to make sure your last loop doesn't include those, or start your last loop at 2 rather than 0.

You want to *add one* to the floored square root to make sure it is tested for:

```
for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
```

I'd use booleans rather than `0` and `1`, by the way, just for clarity (there is not much of a performance or memory footprint difference here):

```
def prime_numbers(n):
    sieve = [True] * (n + 1)  # create a list n elements long
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            for j in range(i * 2, n + 1, i):
                sieve[j] = False
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            print(i)
```

I used `[..] * (n + 1)` to create a list of `n` items (plus 0); this produces a list with `n` shallow copies of the contents of the left operand. That's faster than a list comprehension, and the shared references are fine since `True` is a singleton in Python.

Demo:

```
>>> prime_numbers(31)
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
```

Note that 31 is included there; your code would have resulted in incorrect output as you'd have left in all the multiples of 5.